# XML problem in web.xml first line of the code

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: Crash image]my web.xml file is showing error in the first line

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

the error i am getting is

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>`.
```

Answer (score 0):

The link is not present - http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.5.xsd

Try using one of the version which is available here - http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

Comment: This url points to the latest spring version. In case you want to use a different version then try to import that namespace in spring configuration file.

Comment: can you please check the error that i am getting. i edited the code

Comment: can you paste the whole stacktrace and the web.xml file ?